# JPA: default column name mapping for @ManyToOne relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

When we have a class:

```
@Entity
Order implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
OrderLine implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    Order order;
    ...
}
```

What *row name* will the property **order** map to?

`order_id, ORDER_ID or Order_id?`

**(ommiting the @JoinColumn(name='order_id') is deliberate)**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is what the JPA 1.0 specification writes about the `JoinColumn` annotation:

> #### 9.1.6 JoinColumn Annotation
>
> ...
>
> The `name` annotation element defines
>   the name of the foreign key column.
>   The remaining annotation elements
>   (other than `referencedColumnName`)
>   refer to this column and have the same
>   semantics as for the Column
>   annotation.
>
> If there is a single join column, and
>   if the `name` annotation member is
>   missing, the join column name is
>   formed as the concatenation of the
>   following: the name of the referencing
>   relationship property or field of the
>   referencing entity; "_"; the name of
>   the referenced primary key column. If
>   there is no such referencing
>   relationship property or field in the
>   entity (i.e., a join table is used),
>   the join column name is formed as the
>   concatenation of the following: the
>   name of the entity; "_"; the name of
>   the referenced primary key column.
>
> ...

So in your example, the default name of the foreign key column would be `order_id`.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 9.1.6 "JoinColumn Annotation"

Comment: Are you sure JPA always maps to lower case? During Google searches I found that some say JPA sometimes maps to upper case table and field names.

Comment: @Kdeveloper For JPA 1.0: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=220 and for JPA 2.0: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317

Comment: @Kdeveloper The spec says *"the name of the referencing relationship property or field of the referencing entity (...)"* in your case, it's `order`; then "\_"; and then `id` which is the name of the referenced primary key column.

Answer (score 50):

I might not understand your question.  However, don't you need something like below?

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="order_id", nullable=false)
Order order;
```

[here are some examples](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Example_of_cascaded_primary_keys_and_mixed_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_mapping_annotations)

Comment: I need to know the default mapping, thus how will JPA map the property without a 'name' attribute.

Comment: @KDeveloper if field name is order in my case, hibernate 6.2.13.Final creates order_orderId.